# Make a searchbar filter in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, searchbar

Hi everyone i just wanted to mention first that i'm new to JS and React. I would like to make a Search bar to filter my Job Offers with the title, but i have no clue how to proceed. I already made some tests but my code is different from each example i saw, and i couldnt add the search bar function to my code. Here is my code :

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card'




const JobApplicationList = () => {

    
    
    const [jobapps, setJobapps] = useState([
       
           
       {
       title: 'Développeur MySQL PHP Symfony',
       company: 'Sony',
       city: 'Paris',
       description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.',
       id: 23123
       },

       {
        title: 'Développeur MySQL ',
       company: 'Corsair',
       city: 'Bordeaux',
       description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.',
        id: 231233
        },

        {
            title: 'Développeur PHP Symfony',
            company: 'Logitech',
            city: 'Lille',
            description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.',
         id: 2312353
        },

        {
            title: 'Développeur MERN ',
            company: 'Ubisoft',
            city: 'Montreal',
            description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.',
         id: 2312350
        },

        {
            title: 'Développeur AJAX',
            company: 'Microsoft',
            city: 'Paris',
            description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.',
         id: 2312354
        },
    
   ]);


   
const JobApplication = ({title,company,city,description}) => {
    return (
 
     <div className="card_">
             <Card style={{ width: '100%' }}>
                 <Card.Body>
                     <Card.Title>{title}</Card.Title>
                     <Card.Subtitle className="mb-2 text-muted">{company} | {city}</Card.Subtitle>
                     <Card.Text>
                         {description}
                     </Card.Text>
                     <Card.Link href="#">Learn more</Card.Link>
                     <Card.Link href="#">Apply</Card.Link>
     
                 </Card.Body>
             </Card>
        </div>
 
        
    )
 }
   return(
        
        <div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter item to be searched"  onChange={(e)=>this.searchSpace(e)} />
      {JobApplication}
      
        {jobapps.map(jobapp =>(
            <JobApplication title={jobapp.title} company={jobapp.company} city={jobapp.city} description={jobapp.description} key={jobapp.id}/>
        ))}
        </div>
        
    )

}
export default JobApplicationList;
```

I would appreciate a little bit of help, to make this search bar. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card";

const JobApplicationList = () => {
   const [jobapps, setJobapps] = useState([
   {
  title: "Développeur MySQL PHP Symfony",
  company: "Sony",
  city: "Paris",
  description:
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
  id: 23123,
},

{
  title: "Développeur MySQL ",
  company: "Corsair",
  city: "Bordeaux",
  description:
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
  id: 231233,
},

{
  title: "Développeur PHP Symfony",
  company: "Logitech",
  city: "Lille",
  description:
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
  id: 2312353,
},

{
  title: "Développeur MERN ",
  company: "Ubisoft",
  city: "Montreal",
  description:
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
  id: 2312350,
},

{
  title: "Développeur AJAX",
  company: "Microsoft",
  city: "Paris",
  description:
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
  id: 2312354,
},
]);
//create query state to hold search value
const [query, setQuery] = useState("");

 return (
<div>
  {/*  give your quert state as value and update it on change*/}
  <input
    type="text"
    placeholder="Enter item to be searched"
    value={query}
    onChange={(e) => setQuery(e.target.value)}
  />
  {/*filter it by title before mapping*/}
  {jobapps
    .filter((jobapp) => jobapp.title.search(query) !== -1)
    .map((jobapp) => (
      <JobApplication
        title={jobapp.title}
        company={jobapp.company}
        city={jobapp.city}
        description={jobapp.description}
        key={jobapp.id}
      />
    ))}
    </div>
   );
  };

 //put it as separate component
  const JobApplication = ({ title, company, city, description }) => {
   return (
    <div className="card_">
  <Card style={{ width: "100%" }}>
    <Card.Body>
      <Card.Title>{title}</Card.Title>
      <Card.Subtitle className="mb-2 text-muted">
        {company} | {city}
      </Card.Subtitle>
      <Card.Text>{description}</Card.Text>
      <Card.Link href="#">Learn more</Card.Link>
      <Card.Link href="#">Apply</Card.Link>
       </Card.Body>
       </Card>
    </div>
   );
    };
  export default JobApplicationList;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, its working, and i actually understand everything !